# No folders showing up when connecting Moto G4 via MTP

Tags: mtp, motorola-moto-g-4g

I just recently bought a Moto G4 and I'm trying to put files on it, however upon attempting to use the MTP mode, neither my SD card or internal drive show up in the phone's MTP folder.

[image: Img1]

Moto G4 clearly shows up. However..

[image: img2]

There is nothing in that drive. I have switched it between PTP and MTP just to see if it could detect either, but neither showed up at all. Developer settings are enabled, along with adb/root. My phone is using Lineage 14.1's latest nightly.

What do I do?

EDIT: I've discovered that the SD card can show up, so long as it's formatted to be portable. It will not show up if it's formatted for internal.

Comment: Double check the MTP drivers are installed correctly on your Windows 10. or force them with Intel Android MTP Drivers at https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices

Comment: I think it had somewhat to do with LineageOS. The computer slowly saw my internal storage, and I ended up 50:50 partitioning the SD card so it can be read portably from my reader and MTP. Somewhat solved, but I still can't access the other partition of the SD card. As I said, I 50:50'd them as a remedy to this.